# Need help understanding function in BSL (DrRacket)

Tags: racket, racket-student-languages

Language BSL - DrRacket (racket variant)

Problem: I need to understand what the function below does exactly. Specifically the substring bit, I don't understand how it determines whether a string has an "?" at the end in choosing whether to append "?" to the consumed string.

```
(define (ensure-question str)
  (if (string=? (substring str (- (string-length str) 1)) "?")
      str
      (string-append str "?")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`(substring s position)`** function returns substring of string `s` from certain position. For example : 
`(substring "Apple" 1)` returns `"pple"` since we are taking subscript from the first character.

```
(substring "Apple" ( - (string-length "Apple") 1))
```

will return `"e"`.

We are taking subscript including only the last character `(- (string-length str) 1))` and checking whether it equals to `"?"` by using function **`string=?`**.

Comment: Perfect answer. I understand now. Thanks.